# Codecademy using functions with python

Tags: python, function

I am a new programmer learning python with Codeacademy and I am writing a program that takes an argument number and returns the cube of that number and I keep getting the error:

**by_three(1) returned 1 instead of False**
I am trying **to print the cube, not `False`.**

```
 def cube(number):
     return number ** 3

def by_three(number):
    if number % 3:
       return number
    else:
       return False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have went onto codecademy's python tutorial and found the section with this exercise.

Here is the working code:

```
def cube(number):
    return number**3

def by_three(number):
    if number % 3 == 0:
        return cube(number)
    else:
        return False
```

Essentially, the exercise simply wanted you to call the first function if the number was divisible by 3.

Comment: No problem. I'll explain briefly what the second function does in case you are still a little confused. The % in the if statement is division, but the result is the remainder of the operation. So if we were to write that in english instead of python, it would be "if number divided by 3 has no remainder: return the cube of the number."

Answer (score 1):

The return under `if number % 3 == 0:` is not providing the correct calculation. Try the following:

```
def cube(number):
    return number**3

def by_three(number):
    if number % 3 == 0:
        return cube(number)/3
    else:
        return False
```